# R ggplot2: how to add legend if I use dataframe as data input?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-markdown, legend

I have tried any method online but the legend is not automatically showing up. Some previous issue says the usage of dataframe in ggplot2 is not preferable, but I have tried together() method and it doesn't work either. How to fix the bug?
Here is the data:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gtable)
    R = 0.01*c(7.000, 6.800, 6.620, 6.460, 6.330, 6.250, 6.200, 6.160, 6.125, 6.100)
    Maturity = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    c = seq(from=0, to=0, length.out = length(R))
    for (i in 1:length(R)){
      for (j in 1:i){
        c[i] = c[i] + 1/(1+R[j])^Maturity[j]
      }
      c[i] = (1-1/(1+R[i])^Maturity[i])/c[i]
    }
    Forward = seq(from=0, to=0, length.out = length(R))
    for (i in 1:length(R)){
      Forward[i] = (1+R[i+1])^2/(1+R[i])-1
    }
```

Here is the plot code in RMarkDown:

````
    ```{R fig.width=2.7559, fig.height=2.0669291}
    df = data.frame(Maturity=Maturity, ParYield=c, ForwardRate=Forward, R=R)
    p = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Maturity, y=ParYield)) + 
      ggtitle("Curve of Zero-coupon Yield, Par Yield, Forward Yield")+
      labs(x = "Maturity (year)", y = "Par Yield") +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(100*(min(na.omit(Forward), c)-0.01),
                                    100*(max(na.omit(Forward),c)+0.01),by=0.1)/100, 
                         sec.axis = dup_axis(),
                         labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.005)) +
      scale_x_continuous("Maturity", labels=as.character(Maturity), breaks=Maturity, 
                         sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
      theme_classic() +
      geom_line(aes(y=ParYield), size=1) + 
      geom_line(aes(y=R), size=1) + 
      geom_line(aes(y=ForwardRate), size=1) + 
      geom_point(aes(y=ParYield), shape=21, fill=rgb(69/255, 117/255, 180/255), 
                 size=3, stroke=1.5, color="black") +
      geom_point(aes(y=R), shape=22, fill=rgb(145/255, 191/255, 219/255),
                 size=3, stroke=1.5, color="black") +
      geom_point(aes(y=ForwardRate), shape=23, fill=rgb(224/255, 243/255, 248/255),
                 size=3, stroke=1.5, color="black") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5),
            text = element_text(size=15, colour = "black", family = "Calibri"),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, 'cm'),
            axis.line = element_line(size=1),
            axis.ticks = element_line(size=1),
            axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=15)),
            axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(b=15)),
            axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l=15, r=5)),
            axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(l=5, r=15)),
            axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y.right = element_blank())+
            guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch=c(16,21,20),fill=c('r','r','r'))))+
            theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8), legend.justification = c("right", "top"))
    p
````

Comment: If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics, e.g if you want a legend for color move `color = ...` into `aes()`.

Comment: @stefan But the error says: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: Okay. Just checked. Remove the line starting with `guides(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Check this sketch and make the necessary adjustments as I am not clear on how colors must be set. Pay attention to the suggestion from **@stefan** and modify next code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df = data.frame(Maturity=Maturity, ParYield=c, ForwardRate=Forward, R=R)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Maturity, y=ParYield)) + 
  ggtitle("Curve of Zero-coupon Yield, Par Yield, Forward Yield")+
  labs(x = "Maturity (year)", y = "Par Yield") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(100*(min(na.omit(Forward), c)-0.01),
                                100*(max(na.omit(Forward),c)+0.01),by=0.1)/100, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(),
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.005)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Maturity", labels=as.character(Maturity), breaks=Maturity, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(aes(y=ParYield), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=R), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ForwardRate), size=1) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=ParYield,colour='ParYield'), shape=21, fill=rgb(69/255, 117/255, 180/255), 
             size=3, stroke=1.5,show.legend = T) + #Black
  geom_point(aes(y=R,colour='R'), shape=22,
             fill=rgb(145/255, 191/255, 219/255),
             size=3, stroke=1.5) + #Black
  geom_point(aes(y=ForwardRate,colour='ForwardRate'), shape=23,
             fill=rgb(224/255, 243/255, 248/255),
             size=3, stroke=1.5) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5),
        text = element_text(size=15, colour = "black", family = "Calibri"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, 'cm'),
        axis.line = element_line(size=1),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=15)),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(b=15)),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l=15, r=5)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(l=5, r=15)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch=c(16,21,20))))+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8), legend.justification = c("right", "top"))+
  labs(color='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

Other option would be:

```
#Code 2
df = data.frame(Maturity=Maturity, ParYield=c, ForwardRate=Forward, R=R)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Maturity, y=ParYield)) + 
  ggtitle("Curve of Zero-coupon Yield, Par Yield, Forward Yield")+
  labs(x = "Maturity (year)", y = "Par Yield") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(100*(min(na.omit(Forward), c)-0.01),
                                100*(max(na.omit(Forward),c)+0.01),by=0.1)/100, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(),
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.005)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Maturity", labels=as.character(Maturity), breaks=Maturity, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(aes(y=ParYield), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=R), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ForwardRate), size=1) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=ParYield,colour='ParYield'), shape=21,
             fill=rgb(69/255, 117/255, 180/255), 
             size=3, stroke=1.5,show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(aes(y=R,colour='R'), shape=22,
             fill=rgb(145/255, 191/255, 219/255),
             size=3, stroke=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ForwardRate,colour='ForwardRate'), shape=23,
             fill=rgb(224/255, 243/255, 248/255),
             size=3, stroke=1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black','black','black'))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5),
        text = element_text(size=15, colour = "black", family = "Calibri"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, 'cm'),
        axis.line = element_line(size=1),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=15)),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(b=15)),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l=15, r=5)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(l=5, r=15)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch=c(16,21,20))))+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8), legend.justification = c("right", "top"))+
  labs(color='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That’s great help! I thought I can only input color name in aes(). That should be column name in dataframe.

Comment: @RayJio I will add other option for you! You can adjust other elements if you want.

Comment: @RayJio Done, you can customize further with `guides()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to map some additional aesthetics to variables in your data. I accomplished this by pivoting your data to a longer format.

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(-Maturity, names_to = "Yield", values_to = "Rate")
```

Then, I only used one `geom_line` and one `geom_point`, but with the new `Yield` variable mapped to `group`, `fill`, and `shape`. Now you can use `scale_shape_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` to set the appearances the way you want.

```
p = ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = Maturity, y = Rate, group = Yield,
                         fill = Yield, shape = Yield)) + 
  ggtitle("Curve of Zero-coupon Yield, Par Yield, Forward Yield")+
  labs(x = "Maturity (year)", y = "Yield") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(100*(min(na.omit(Forward), c)-0.01),
                                100*(max(na.omit(Forward),c)+0.01),by=0.1)/100, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(),
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.005)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Maturity", labels=as.character(Maturity), breaks=Maturity, 
                     sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(size=1) + 
  geom_point(size=3, stroke=1.5, color="black") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("ParYield" = 21, "R" = 22, "ForwardRate" = 23),
                     labels = c("Par Yield", "Zero-coupon Yield", "Forward Yield")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ParYield" = rgb(69/255, 117/255, 180/255), 
                               "R" = rgb(145/255, 191/255, 219/255), 
                               "ForwardRate" = rgb(224/255, 243/255, 248/255)),
                    labels = c("Par Yield", "Zero-coupon Yield", "Forward Yield")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, hjust=0.5),
        text = element_text(size=15, colour = "black", family = "Calibri"),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, 'cm'),
        axis.line = element_line(size=1),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t=15)),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(margin = margin(b=15)),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l=15, r=5)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(l=5, r=15)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch=c(16,21,20),fill=c('r','r','r'))))+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8), legend.justification = c("right", "top"))
```

[image]

I would recommend rethinking your y axis labels.'